# Is the word "unsaint" used in English?

Tags: word-usage

Do casual native English speakers understand the word **unsaint** as the opposite to the word **saint**? Or do they interpret it as something different or even don't understand it at all?

Comment: In the unlikely event anyone needed a word to *specifically* describe someone as "the exact opposite of a saint" in the way OP implies, they'd probably use [antisaint](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22antisaint%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22is+the+antisaint%22&tbm=bks) (along the lines of *antichrist, antipope,* etc.).

Comment: quoting @snailboat "An affix (meaning suffix, prefix, etc.) that can form new words is called productive. Some affixes are more productive than others; for example, the -ness suffix is productive in English, and so is the un- prefix, though to a lesser extent. Even less productive is an affix like -ar, as in circular; we rarely use it to form new words. "

Answer (score 2):

It's listed as a [verb](http://www.onelook.com/?w=unsaint), but it's not a common word. I believe the adjective *[unsaintly](http://www.onelook.com/?w=unsaintly)* is more common.

You can have a look at the [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unsaint,%20unsaintly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), if you want. It shows that *unsaint* has been rarely used over the past century, while *unsaintly* has had some steady use.

If you asked me for an opposite of the word *saint*, I'd probably suggest *sinner*. I usually think of *saint* as a noun first, not a verb, and the expression [*saints and sinners*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unsaint,unsaintly,saints%20and%20sinners,%20sinners%20and%20saints&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) gets used more often than *unsaint* and *unsaintly* combined.

Answer (score 0):

"Unsaint" sounds like it wants to be a verb, but "saint" is not used as a verb in English. The verb for this process in Catholicism is "beatify" or "canonize" which would imply that the opposite should be "debeatify" or "decanonize" but I am not sure if this has ever happened.  However, the dictionary does list "unsaint" as a verb and I think it would be understood in context.

Comment: _Saint_ is not used as a verb in English? Perhaps it's not common, but [it is indeed used](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22was%20sainted%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1935,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&safe=active).